# how to save file with savedilogue javafx

Tags: excel, javafx, save

I have created excel file and I want that file to show as "File Name" box in JavaFx file chooser. So I can save that file wherever I want with the use of SaveDialogueBox.

Code :

```
WriteExcelFile test = new WriteExcelFile();    

File exlFile = new File("c:/temp/"+tabName+".xls");
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFile, wbSettings);
workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
//createLabel(excelSheet);

Label label;
// Write a few headers
label = new Label(0, 0,"ID");
excelSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 0,"BIC");
excelSheet.addCell(label);

label = new Label(0, 1,"Hi 0");
excelSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 1,"Hi 1");
excelSheet.addCell(label);

workbook.write();
workbook.close();

Stage stage = (Stage) delBtn.getScene().getWindow();
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
        new ExtensionFilter("Microsoft Workbook", "*.xls"));

File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
if (selectedFile != null) {
    //What to write here
}
```

Comment: What are the `WritableWorkbook ` and `WritableSheet `?

Comment: It will create workbook and worksheet fot .xls.

Comment: Does one of them have a `saveTo(file)` or `writeTo(file)` method?

Comment: Another possibility is that you could get the content that the worksheet would save to the file as a `String` or `byte[]` and write it to the file yourself.

Comment: Did you find the answer? If not could you post a link to the docs for `WritableWorkbook `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I got the answer in a different way.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBuilder;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;


/**
 *
 * @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
 */
public class JavaFXText extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        Group root = new Group();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("poi-test.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");

            // index from 0,0... cell A1 is cell(0,0)
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);

            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
            cellA1.setCellValue("Hello");
            HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.createCell((short) 1);
            cellB1.setCellValue("Goodbye");
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellB1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.createCell((short) 2);
            cellC1.setCellValue(true);

            HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.createCell((short) 3);
            cellD1.setCellValue(new Date());
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat
                    .getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
            cellD1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//        Text textSong = TextBuilder.create()
//                .text
//                .build();                

        Button buttonSave = ButtonBuilder.create()
                .text("Save")
                .build();

        buttonSave.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

          @Override
          public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
              FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

              //Set extension filter
              FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("excel files (*.xls)", "*.xls");
              fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

              //Show save file dialog
              File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

              if(file != null){
                  SaveFile(file);
                  System.out.println("hi");
              }
          }
      });

        VBox vBox = VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(buttonSave)
                .build();

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void SaveFile(File file){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");

            // index from 0,0... cell A1 is cell(0,0)
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);

            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
            cellA1.setCellValue("Hello");
            HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.createCell((short) 1);
            cellB1.setCellValue("Goodbye");
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellB1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.createCell((short) 2);
            cellC1.setCellValue(true);

            HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.createCell((short) 3);
            cellD1.setCellValue(new Date());
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat
                    .getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
            cellD1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```